# What are ALL the Events triggered when an item is edited?

Tags: events

I have the following code:

```
using (new SecurityDisabler()) {
    using (new EditContext(itemToChange, false, false)) {
        itemToChange[field] = theValue;
    }
}
```

the third parameter of EditContext, if set to true, disables all Events from the enclosed code, making it functionally identical as if it was inside an EventDisabler block.

- If the events are disabled, the change to the field's value is apparently immediately reversed once out of the block;
- If events are enabled, the code works as expected - the changes are apparent both from the UI and on the application.

To make matters more strange, when I disable the Event the changes *sometimes* show up after a considerable amount of time.

My gut feeling tells me that the immediate update is caused by some event I don't know about, different from item:saved, that is firing when the item changes.

**Question**

Does anyone has a comprehensive list of ALL events that fire when an item's field value is changed?

Bonus question: is it possible to selectively disable specific events?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but as an FYI you should consider moving away from using EditContext() - https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/01/EditContext-Considered-Harmful/

Comment: Thank you, I amended my code accordingly.

Comment: Can you try to use cache.aspx page to clear all the caches after your change with event disabler enabled?

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: DING DING DING DING!! Marek wins again. If you can explain how without EventDisabler the cache for that item is marked as dirty, the answer is yours.

Comment: That is excellent question but I think it happens too deep in Sitecore item provider world and I'm afraid I won't be able to help with that. If you need to remove that item from cache you may try (I haven't tested that!): `CacheManager.GetItemCache(item.Database).RemoveItem(item.ID);`

Comment: Yes, I have already done that - this solves the last problem I had with this entire event handling. Thanks again.